# How to go back to previous concurrency in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I edit code in vscode, I often use `ctrl + D` to select the next word that matches the current one, but sometimes I would like to return N number of words.

Does anyone know if this is possible in vscode or is there a plugin?

Thanks!

PD. Vim has the plugin Multiline for it

Comment: `return N number of words` : return to what and how to enter N? In VSC it is called `Multi Cursor` not `concurrency`, give a better example of what you want, give a link of the doc describing the vim functionality

Comment: I dont know how to make it so visual, but when you are coding in vscode, if you press `ctrl D` you will select a full word, and if you press again, you will select the next match and so on... So, I just wanna know if there a re some way to go back to the last word that was selected with ` ctrl D` and instead go ahead with the next, go back to the previous one.

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+U` and `Ctrl+K Ctrl+D`

Comment: Omg that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much dude!

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by the user rioV8 was just the solution to what I needed.

Use `Ctrl+U` to go to the previous match and `Ctrl+K Ctrl+D` to jump to the next match without selecting the current one.

Thanks!